# Generlized eigenvalues of matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a generalized eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation}
Av = \lambda Bv,
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are matrices. If $B = I$, we have an ordinary eigenvalue problem and if we want to know the eigenvalues of $A^n$, we know that they will be $\lambda^n$. Is there a similar result for the generalized eigenvalue problem? It is not straightforward as
\begin{equation}
A^2v = A(\lambda Bv) = \lambda ABv,
\end{equation}
which cannot be further simplified unless $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Hint: Write $Bv$ as a linear combination of your generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Do you mean like this? Say $Bv_n = \sum_m a_mv_m$. Then $A^kv_n = A^{k-1}\lambda_nBv_n = \lambda_nA^{k-1}\sum_{m_1}a_{m_1}v_{m_1}$. Repeating $k$ times gives $\lambda_n\sum_{m_1,...m_k}a_{m_1}\dots a_{m_k}\lambda_{m_1}\dots \lambda_{m_k}$. Can I somehow continue from  this or does it simply show that there is no nice expression? (Nice meaning getting rid of the $a$s.)

Comment: I don't it reduces particularly nicely no...

Comment: The answer is no, there is no such result